# Bind Prefix with one Parent View Model MVC

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created one ViewModel which contains all the models which i want to bind to view.

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public IList<Incentive> USAIncentive { get; set; }
  public IList<Incentive> EMEAIncentive { get; set; }
  public IList<Incentive> LACIncentive { get; set; }
  ...............................
}
```

On Click of Save button I am getting this data from view. I am using something like this to get back the data and save in DB.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix = "USAIncentive")]List<Incentive> USAIncentive,[Bind(Prefix = "EMEAIncentive")]List<Incentive> EMEAIncentive,
     [Bind(Prefix = "JAPIncentive")]List<Incentive> JAPIncentive,[Bind(Prefix = "CanadaIncentive")]List<Incentive> CanadaIncentive
        ..................................................
        )
```

Like this i have twenty models which i need to bind it with prefix here.
Now my question why i cannot directly bind my ViewModel class so that all the models defined inside this class i can get at once instead of writing all the models one by one.
I trie dthat but i get the value as null. Individul model gives me values correctly.

After that i need to pass one by one model to my createxml method which is creating the xml.
If i get at once i can create xml at one go instead of calling createxml twenty times.

```
Utility.CreateXML(USAIncentive);
```

In View :

```
@model ViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

Accessing like this one by one :

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.USAIncentive.Count; i++){}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by " why i cannot directly bind my ViewModel class so that all the models defined inside this class i can get at once instead of writing all the models one by one".  Are you asking why you need to separate out the models as separate parameters in your `Save` action?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly.why you need to separate out the models as separate parameters in your Save action? I want to get this collection at once.

Comment: You do not need to separate out the models. If the method is `public ActionResult Save(ViewModel model)` everything will be correctly bound. If its not, your doing something else wrong.